# Allow database access between two mobile applications?

Tags: database, android-studio, kotlin, cordova

I am working with two different applications:

1. Android studio - Kotlin application - SQLite Database
2. React.js - Cordova application - MySQL Database

These two applications need to be able to *get information* from each-others database. These databases already exist and solutions requiring reinstalling the applications can't be used.

I have looked into **Content Providers** but is this a valid solution in this case? Is there other solutions better suited?

Comment: If the apps can't be reinstalled, then yes, a content provider is the way to go.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thank you for your answer, just to clarify for myself before I dive into the solution. The Content provider solution will work both ways even though one of the apps are written in react.js?

Comment: It should. Even if Cordova can't access it directly, there should be a bridge or something. If I remember correctly, I recall people writing plugins in Java that could be used from within Phone Gap/Cordova. Now, I know your other app is in Kotlin, but worst case scenario, you may have to go that same route. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html